# Manipulating Masks for doubles on Xeon Phi

Tags: intrinsics, intel-mic, xeon-phi

I am doing conditional computations on a Xeon Phi using intrinsic functions.
I have to use double values so i need a __mmask8.
As long as I use some of the compare functions there is no problem for me, but if I want to modify those masks I run into some type conflicts.
Where the [documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/hh_goto.htm#GUID-FC13EE09-8555-414B-8FF2-D7D66CD3975C.htm) gives me plenty of functions to modify __mmask16 used for single precision there is not a single one usable for double precision.

I want to do someting like the following:

```
int tmp = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) { 
    tmp = index[i];
    tmp = tmp << 1;
}
__mmask8 something = _mm512_int2mask(tmp);
```

The documentation provides the given function only for a __mmask16.
The same comes with all manipulating functions in the [Vector Mask Intrinsic chapter](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/hh_goto.htm#GUID-5A68F64D-8650-42B7-9AD6-D1B6F98D674C.htm) of the Documentation.

Can i use those functions as well?

Is there a convention like "use every second bit of a __mmask16" ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-xeon-phi-coprocessor-vector-microarchitecture

> Each VPU has 128 entry 512-bit vector registers divided up among the
>   threads, thus getting 32 entries per thread. These are
>   hard-partitioned. There are eight 16-bit mask registers per thread
>   which are part of the vector register file. The mask registers act as
>   a filter per element for the 16 elements and thus allows one to
>   control which of the 16 32-bit elements are active during a
>   computation. **For double precision the mask bits are the bottom 8 bits.**

Intel doesn't provide any intrinsics for operating on __mmask8 types; all of the intrinsics are for __mmask16. Therefore I assume that we're expected to just use the __mmask16 intrinsics for manipulating __mask8 types. This seems to work, but I've had very little experience with these so far.

Comment: just had time to test this fully. your suggestion is fully correct.
One additional information for futher readers:
In a __mmask8 the other bits are discarded so casting back to __mmask16 only contains the used 8 bit of the __mmask8